# Angular 13 i18n switches to en-US when I try to access some of the routes in the other language

Tags: angular2-routing, github-pages, angular-i18n, angular13

I hosted my angular 13 website on Github Pages and after I added i18n I have the following routing problem.

When I go to https://MyRepoName.github.io/base/en-US/ everything is fine and I get redirected to https://MyRepoName.github.io/base/en-US/home as it should.

**But when I want to access some other route for example:
https://MyRepoName.github.io/base/en-US/welcome then I got redirected to https://MyRepoName.github.io/base/home**

When I go to https://MyRepoName.github.io/base/welcome then everything is fine.

I have this code for routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'welcome',
    component: WelcomeComponent
},
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
},
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home',  }
```

];

If someone had the same issue pls help.

I have 1 index/404 file with   `<base href="/base/">`
and folder en-US with index/404 file   `<base href="/base/en-US">`

I also receive this info when I access: https://MyRepoName.github.io/base/welcome

```
Router Event: Od
NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/en-US/welcome')
Od {id: 1, url: '/en-US/welcome', navigationTrigger: 'imperative', restoredState: null}

Router Event: qR
RoutesRecognized(id: 1, url: '/en-US/welcome', urlAfterRedirects: '/home', state:Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') } )
qR {id: 1, url: '/en-US/welcome', urlAfterRedirects: '/home', state: ob}
```